# Is there a way to escape `|` inside tables?

Tags: org-table, pipe

If I tab this:

```
| Expression | Meaning |
|---+---|
| /a|b/ | a or b |
```

I get this:

```
| Expression | Meaning |        |
|------------+---------+--------|
| /a         | b/      | a or b |
|            |         |        |
```

Is there a workaround?

https://orgmode.org/manual/Tables.html

Comment: It depends on what you are looking for. The answer describes the [standard recommendation (see footnote)](https://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-Table-Editor.html) to have a vertical bar when exporting. There is no way to escape it in the Org mode buffer itself. See [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76746/how-to-make-monospace-vertical-bar-character-in-orgmode-table) for some other possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me `\vert{}` works as in:

```
| Expression  | Meaning |
|-------------+---------|
| /a\vert{}b/ | a or b  |
```

HTML output:
[image]